# Azure SQL Data Warehouse -- storage billing

Tags: azure-synapse

How does MAXSIZE affect billing? I see that the default value is now 240TBs. What if I'm only using 10TB of space? Will I still be charged for the entire 240TB size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's a configuration change that **allows your DW to grow to that size**. You only get billed for actual usage, rounded up to the next TB.